# MongoDB match a document even if the field value is more specific than the one in the document

Tags: regex, mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

I have this basic Mongo Document:

```
{version: "v1.5"}
```

The problem that I'm having is that when I use: `db.coll.find({version: "/v1.5/i"})` it returns the document, but if I have more than 1.5 specified like this `db.coll.find({version: "/v1.5.1/i"})` it doesn't return the document.

In MySQL I can just do: `SELECT * IN versions WHERE CONCAT('%', field, '%') = "1.5.1"`

How would I make it return the document if the version is more specific than in the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use optional parameter regex, placing :

```
v1\.5(\.\d)??
```

That means on app side you need to check how many dots exists in given version field, and decide

1. truncate everything after second dot (dot included)
2. add regex above to treat extra data as `optional group`

btw - please escape dot in you regex as this could match version `v125` or `v1a5` too.

Comment: I gave version as an example, but it did help me solve the problem that I was having.